# Qt. Реализация двух и более параллельных процессов

Tags: qt, многопоточность, qthread

Обращаюсь за помощью, так как уже неделю не могу разобраться. Я не программист, но приходится этим заниматься по роду деятельности. Поэтому я даже не могу сформулировать запрос грамотно, чтоб нашлись решения. Прошу прощения, если дублирую вопрос, я пытался что-то найти. Моя задача написать программу, которая снимает показания с одного прибора и на их основе меняет параметры двух других. Причем все эти процессы должны быть запущены одновременно. Я через костыли умудрился запараллелить 2 процесса, но три уже так не сделать.

**Ближе к делу отсюда.**
При создании приложения на Qt имеем класс MainWindow. Через него создаем окно в главном потоке. В этом же главном потоке пользователь предварительно настраивает параметры общения со всеми приборами, после чего запускает сам эксперимент. Для каждого процесса я создаю отдельный класс и перемещаю его в тред (movetothread). Но проблема в том, что настройка всех параметров происходит в главном потоке из-за чего все созданные объекты внутри класса ассоциированы с этим главным потоком и я не могу их обрабатывать в других потоках. Но при этом заранее эти параметры неизвестны и я не могу их создать внутри неглавных потоков сразу (или по крайней мере не понимаю как). Мне нужно через окно опросить пользователя и уже потом как-то передать информацию в другие потоки. Причем загвоздка в том, что я не могу сделать этот опрос внутри методов класса, так как они будут вне зоны видимости, из-за чего другие методы не могут на них ссылаться, а если я инициализирую их при создании класса, то при создании объекта класса в главном потоке они опять будут ассоциироваться с ним. Задача похожа на классическую, но нагуглить не могу, хоть убей. Даже чатЖПТ не понимает, что я хочу. Каким образом обычно решаются такие задачи? Заранее прошу прощения за сумбур.

Comment: Вам не надо запускать поток и потом как-то из этого потока пытаться достать параметры из главного окна. Надо чтобы главное окно считало параметры в структуру и запустило дочерний поток, передав ему эти параметры на вход. А дальше пусть поток молотит. Между отдельными потоками передавать информацию сигналами

Comment: @BeardedBeaver
Я для общения с приборами пользуюсь QModbusClient тоесть формально мне нужно где-то создать объект типа QModbusTcpClient. После чего я должен к нему обращаться для того, чтоб проверить подключение или уже начать сам длительный эксперимент.
Правильно ли я понял вас, что если я создам в главном окне этот объект, запихну ссылку на него в структуру, а потом передам эту структуру в дочерний поток через сигнал, то он сможет обрабатывать этот объект?

Comment: Я бы делал не так. Я бы в дочерний поток передал параметры того, как создавать QModbusTcpClient, а создал бы его уже в дочернем потоке на месте

Comment: @BeardedBeaver прошу прощения, но я не понял, в чем разница между тем, что я описал в комментарии и тем, что описали вы. Мне же все равно нужно как-то передавать набор информации, а значит создать разного рода объекты в главном окне.

Comment: Создание QObject или его наследника в основном потоке и передача его в другой поток несет некоторые побочные эффекты, касающиеся цикла обработки событий. Тогда как "обычные" структуры данных можно передавать без этих побочных эффектов. Чтобы не париться с ними, я предлагаю в основном потоке создать объект настроек, передать его в дочерний поток и в дочернем потоке на месте создать QModbusTcpClient

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Все, понял, что вы имеете ввиду. Спасибо за помощь. Судя по всему другого выхода нет и придется создавать так. Однако сразу возникает вопрос. Я не очень пока понимаю архитектуру  Qt, а если гуглить, то огромное количество информации просто в кашу превращается, поэтому, пользуясь случаем и вашим терпением хочу спросить. При создании главного окна оно буквально "просто создается и ждет" моей реакции. Можно ли каким-то образом сделать второй поток таким. Условно, создал поток, потом нажал кнопку - он инициализировался, нажал другую - он начал что-то обрабатывать итд.

Comment: Я так понял тут как-то замешан QEventLoop, но вообще не выкупил, что это такое и как пользоваться. ChaGPT вообще говорит, мол, ничего не надо. Просто с этим вводными с инициализацией на месте я вообще не могу придумать, как программу грамотно построить. Мне же нужно в любой момент и проверить соединение и потом через него что-то передать и посчитать в любой момент.

Comment: Здесь нужно больше подробностей по вашей архитектуре, это за скоупом данного вопроса. Я в целом готов вам помочь. У меня в профиле здесь указана ссылка на гитхаб, на гитхабе публично видимый email. Напишите мне туда, постараемся что-нибудь придумать

Comment: @BeardedBeaver большое спасибо, нашел вашу почту, но так почему-то и не смог отправить письмо. Наверное, неловко, что буду нагружать вас. Вы и так мне помогли, буду пробовать что-то двигать сам. Еще раз благодарю.

Comment: Наше дело предложить

Answer (score 0):

Короче, решение лежало на поверхности. Так как оба прибора сами обрабатывали все операции, мне не нужен был тред. По сути хватило QTimer и QCoreApplication::processEvents() под все нужны. Причем в нашел статейку, где писали, что подобные вещи только так и делаются, что обработка через равные промежутки времени, что асинхронное общение приборов.